# Connected CW-complex which is not locally finite

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

I am working on Topological Complexity of robot motion  planning. I am looking for a connected CW-complex which is not metrizable. I have found that:

> **Proposition 3.8.** A connected CW complex $X$ is metrizable if and only if it is locally finite.
>
> A CW complex is *locally finite* if each cell is disjoint from all but finitely many cells of $X$.
>
> **Proposition 10.1.8.** A CW complex is locally compact iff it is locally finite.
>
> **Proposition 1.5.12** A locally finite and connected CW-complex $X$ is countable.

So I have came up with the following example:

A graph with vertices the irrational numbers and edges the intervals between two consecutive ones.

According to the last proposition it shouldn't be locally finite (and intuition also says the same here).

What do you think about the example? Is there an easier one out there that I am missing?

Comment: I dare you to describe explicitly a single edge in that graph of yours. In other words: what do you mean by "consecutive irrationals"?

Comment: @Arthur you are right. I was thinking about something like a fractal or something weird like that. 

I meant, you start with an infinite number of irrationals but such that the family is locally finite and form the edges. Then you start adding irrationals and creating new edges when the one you add is consecutive to other two. Something fractal using a similar heuristic to the one used when you define Cantor set. But I explained myself badly and I am still doing so I'm afraid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such thing as "consecutive irrational numbers". What would the number that comes after $\sqrt{2}$ be? Between two irrational numbers there is always another one... Your CW complex doesn't exist.

For an example of a connected, uncountable CW complex, you can for example take this one: it has a single 0-cell, and an uncountable number of edges joining the 0-cell to itself. In other words, the wedge sum of an uncountable number of circles. It's clearly connected and uncountable, and as you can see it's not locally finite because the vertex meets an infinite number of cells.

Comment: How do you show that this example has coherent topology (W in CW)?

Comment: It might be a silly remark but it really confused me the first time a read this answer: A cell here means a _closed_ cell. This differes from Hatcher's, where a cell is the image of the difference $D\setminus \partial D^n$. I'm also surprised no one tried to pick up the OP's idea of using irrational numbers and order them using the Axiom of Choice.